# How to use emacsclient in terminal to switch git branches?

Tags: magit, emacsclient, terminal-emacs

I'm trying to make a setup that will use emacs as a command line tool to switch git branches.

The idea is to run some command in terminal, something like `emacsclient -t -e "(magit-checkout)"`. This will run emacs window with `(magit-checkout)` command executed in my terminal. I can then select a branch from the list, press enter, emacs will then checkout this branch, window will close and I'm back to my terminal.

I can't make it work though, running `emacsclient -t -e "(magit-checkout)"` just flashes emacs window in my terminal and closes it immediately. It works almost as I want it to work with `(magit-commit)` command (the only thing that doesn't work is that emacs window won't close after the operation is done). But it doesn't work with `(magit-checkout)`. Is there any way to make it work the way I described?

Comment: `magit-checkout` needs one argument, you can try `emacsclient -t -e "(call-interactively #'magit-checkout)"` instead. Personally, I use only `magit-status` (something like `emacsclient -t -e '(magit-status)'`) and start various git operation from the status buffer.

Comment: the comment from @xuchunyang might solve the problem for you. However, Emacs can be a bit awkward when used as a command-line tool. The usual magit workflow is to do everything from Emacs, so you don't need to switch back and forth between Emacs and your terminal. Magit provides all your git features, and you can compile, browse directories, and even run terminals (via M-x shell or M-x eshell) from Emacs as well. What you're doing is fine of course, there are no rules! But it might be worth investigating how to do the stuff you're doing in your terminal in Emacs instead.

Comment: Why do you want to use Emacs to switch git branches? Wouldn't it be far easier to use git check out a different branch? Is it for the branch list and selection?

Comment: Thank you @xuchunyang, this works great! Can I ask if may be you also know how to achieve this "close the emacs window after the branch is selected" behaviour? It's not a big deal, but it's nice to have.

Comment: @zck To use git checkout from a command line you either need to remember a branch's name, or you need to copypaste it from somewhere. Sometimes you remember part of the branch's name, but zsh won't allow you to fuzzy search on that. zsh would allow you to search by branche's first letters, but unfortunatelly our branches are prefixed with issue number, so it's not very convenient to do it this way.

Usually I print all the branches and then copypaste the right one to the terminal. But it's quite a bit of clicking and typing for a routine operation. With magit I can fuzzy search branches.

Comment: @DmitryRyadnenko You can type `C-x 5 0` or use `emacsclient -t -e "(call-interactively #'magit-checkout)" -e "(delete-frame)"`. However, I think you cam simply use `emacsclient -e "(magit-status)"` then checkout/commit/diff/pull/etc from here. I prefer this way since I am not familiar with the git command line interface.

Comment: @DmitryRyadnenko I also use long branch names with a issue number prefix which are not nice for tab-completion or manual typing, so I wrote https://stackoverflow.com/a/23532744/324105 so that I could use short aliases in place of the real branch names.  It's not what you're asking for, but I'm sure you would find it beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outlined in the comments by others you can use something like:

```
 emacsclient -t -e "(call-interactively #'magit-checkout)" -e "(delete-frame)"
```

Of course you would have to create a script or alias for that.

But like the users who have commented on your questions, I too would recommend using either plain old `git checkout` or going all in with Magit, doing everything from there. If you stick to the former, then you should look into teaching Zsh's completion mechanism about fuzzy matching - I would assume that that is possible somehow.